# woocommerce coupons description in order email

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I've got a problem to show coupon description in thank you order mail.

I have name of coupon by using:

```
$order->get_used_coupons()
```

But above function returns only namen. Any one know how to get description for specific coupon name?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
$coupons = $order->get_items( 'coupon' );
  foreach ( $coupons as $item_id => $item ) {
    echo "<span class='coupon-name'><b>".$item['name']."</b></span>";
    $post = get_post( $item_id );
    echo "<p class='coupon-description'>".$post->post_excerpt."</p>";
  }
}
```